# What is the benefit of putting async on a WebAPI controller action that performs no await operations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I was recently asked an interview question for .NET WebAPI and it went like this...

Interviewer:

> Is there any benefit to adding `async` to the method signature of a WebAPI controller action that **does not** perform any async operations?

My answer:

> No, because there is no blocking code in the method which means the controller action should run synchronously in its own thread from the thread Pool. Is that correct?

Interviewer:

> No, it's actually not.

I've searched the web for about 15-20 minutes to find a conclusive answer but have not been fully satisfied with the answers... So, am I right or was the interviewer right?

To further clarify the question: Would load testing a WebAPI controller action in this case perform better under load just because it has an async keyword places in the signature even though it has no async code in it?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: In those situations, I would say to the interviewer afterwards. "Thanks for that question re: (whatever). I wasn't aware of that. Are you able to send me a link to an article that talks more about that?"

Comment: Can you post it as an answer so you can get some SO credit? @SLaks

Comment: The `async` modifier on it's own does nothing.

Comment: Thx @mjwills. That’s a great follow up question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async` modifier on it's own does nothing.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async):

> If the method that the `async` keyword modifies doesn't contain an `await` expression or statement, the method executes synchronously. A compiler warning alerts you to any `async` methods that don't contain `await` statements, because that situation might indicate an error.

Comment: "does nothing *useful*" I would say. A small test indicates a lot of IL is generated for an `async` method that does not contain any `await`. Not sure why the state machine is generated if the compiler does not detect an `await` though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Have you tested this with activated optimizations (release mode) or debug mode?

Comment: Yes, Debug and Release generate the same IL (related to the state machine, that is)

Answer (score 1):

you are correct, `async` without `await` would be a `Task` running on the current thread (not a new thread) till the end which basically = running synchronously.

If you really want to take into account of everything then marking it as async would add the totally ignorable overhead of creating a `Task`

Comment: The compiler will just wrap the return value in a Task using Task.FromResult or if there is no return value use Task.Completed, i.e. the task will already be created in its completed state without ever running.